# A command that I ran that works wrongly in sed

Tags: bash, sed

this command does not work in sed, version 4.2.1.

```
    sed 's/[[:upper:]]/[[:lower:]]/' <file.
```

although it does detect the upper case pattern, it does not do the conversion to lower case, rather it converts the captured patterns to [[:lower:]]. any workaround?

Comment: Just curious, what are the contents of your ``file`` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sed, you need to capture the upper-case pattern in a group and then substitute with the lowercase version

```
sed -r 's/([[:upper:]])/\L\1/g' <file
```

Comment: Thanks, 1_CR. it worked. the sed tutorial i am reading has no mention of -r or even \L. Maybe I have to read the sed man pages on bash again. thanks. lovely.

Answer (score 2):

Use `tr` instead:

```
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' file
```

Comment: i know tr exists. wanted to know why i couldn't do it with sed when sed supports bre.